# Integral of product of distribution functions

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, density-function

We know that definite integrals over $[0,L]$ of non-uniform distribution functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ equal $1$ for both. The functions can overlap or not, but the distribution isn't otherwise specified, it could be lognormal, gaussian etc. Does it hold for some case that integral over $[0,L]$ for product function $f(x)g(x)$ is greater than one?

Comment: A bit of nitpicking: The domain of integration should be all of $\mathbb{R}$ for $\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx$ to be $1$, when $f$ is a gaussian denstiy.

Comment: 1. Please do not modify your question after answers have been posted. 2. Please add some context to your question, at present there is none. 3. Start by simple cases such as $f(x)=g(x)=2x$ on $(0,1)$ or $f(x)=g(1-x)=2x$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

In a nutshell, it can be any number.

**Example 1.** Consider the case where $a > 0$ and $f = g$ is the density of the uniform distribution over $[-\frac{a}{2}, \frac{a}{2}]$. Then

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \, dx = \int_{-a/2}^{a/2} \frac{1}{a^2} \, dx = \frac{1}{a}. $$

**Example 2.** For each $a > 0$ we can check that

$$ f(x) = g(x) = \dfrac{(-\log x)^{a}}{\Gamma(a+1)} \mathbf{1}_{(0,1)}(x) $$

is a density of some distribution, i.e., it is non-negative and $\int_{0}^{1}f(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} g(x) \, dx = 1$. Then it follows that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)g(x) \, dx = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{(-\log x)^{2a}}{\Gamma(a+1)^2} \, dx = \frac{\Gamma(2a+1)}{\Gamma(a+1)^2}. $$

Again this can be made arbitrarily large by choosing large $a$.

---

*Remark.* Both examples are created by considering distributions that contrates near $0$. Although mathematically nonsensical, the corresponding mental image is that

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x)^2 \, dx \ {``}=\text{''} \ \infty $$

for the "Dirac delta function" $\delta(x)$ which is the "density" of the point mass concentrated at $0$. Both examples can be recognized as a perturbed version of this heuristics.

Comment: Indeed. I had already considered the uniform distribution. Added more specifications, sorry.